# jpgraph x-axis scale in date(Gi) max 2359 not showing data

Tags: php, jpgraph

When using the Jpgrap and set the x-axis scale to 2400

```
$graph->SetScale('intint',0,$max,0,2400);
```

Then insert data where format key is date('Gi'),Hour minute

```
$ydata = array(1820=>5000,1955=>1000,2315=>7500);
$lineplot=new LinePlot($ydata);
```

I do not get any line drawn. only when i use the swatch time (000 ~999) it shows the line.

```
$ydata = array(154=>5000,587=>1000,768=>7500);
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Okey found the answer myself,

```
$graph->SetScale('intint',0,$max,0,2400);
$lineplot=new LinePlot($ydata);
```

needs to be:

```
$graph->SetScale('intint');
$graph->xaxis->SetTickLabels(array_keys($ydata));
$lineplot=new LinePlot(array_values($ydata));
```